# Joomla 4 Get a list of site articles in the module settings

Tags: articles

My code

```
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

use Joomla\CMS\Access\Access;
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Administrator\Extension\ContentComponent;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Helper\RouteHelper;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app = Factory::getApplication('Site');

// Get an instance of the generic articles model
$model = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Articles', 'Site', ['ignore_request' => true]);
$appParams = $app->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
$model->setState('filter.published', ContentComponent::CONDITION_PUBLISHED);
$items = $model->getItems();
```

The first error in the line

```
$appParams = $app->getParams();
```

Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::getParams()

The second error in the line

```
$items = $model->getItems();
```

Call to a member function get() on null

1   ()  JROOT\components\com_content\src\Model\ArticlesModel.php:273

2   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model\ArticlesModel->getListQuery()
JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Model\ListModel.php:215

3   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ListModel->_getListQuery()
JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Model\ListModel.php:264

4   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ListModel->getItems()
JROOT\components\com_content\src\Model\ArticlesModel.php:640

5   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model\ArticlesModel->getItems()
JROOT\administrator\modules\mod_antajaxrequest\articlelist.php:21

Tell me how to get a list of site articles in the administrative panel, in the module parameters?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()` no longer takes any arguments. It always return the active application instance. `Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication` doesn't have a `getParams()` method so that's where the error comes. If really needed, you can get the site application from the service container:

```
Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()->get(Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
```

Using application within application, however, is a bad practice and won't work correctly most of the time. In your case you don't really need this anyways - params from site application are request-specific and will not work correctly in backend. Essentially `SiteApplication::getParams()` is used to merge component params with active menu item params, which are not relevant when running this code in backend or generally when the request is ignored using `ignore_request` option. So you can pass just the component params:

```
$model->setState('params', clone ComponentHelper::getParams('com_content'));
```

Another option would be to, of course, use the backend model instead. It will return the same articles but without running any code that is relevant only to frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Tell me - how to correctly get a list of site articles with pagination in the administrative part?
Thank you.